# Use smart or raw pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

In the code below, there is a `Grid` which contains `points`. Likewise, `Element` and `Face` also have `points` but I want to them to point to `points` in `Grid`.

Should I use smart or raw pointers. If I use smart pointers should I use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`?

```
struct Vector3
{
    vector <double> dim;

    Vector3 ()
    {
        dim.resize(3);
    }
};

struct Element
{
    vector <Vector3*> points;
};

struct Face
{
    vector <Vector3*> points;
};

struct Grid
{
    vector <Vector3> points;

    vector <Element> elms;
    vector <Face> faces;
};
```

Comment: It depends >:] e.g. What is the lifetime of `Grid` vs `Element`? Are the `points` removed from `Grid` at some time, but need still be accessible from `Element`? etc.

Comment: Also, whether the Grid's vector gets resized.

Comment: What does Vector3 contain?

Comment: @dyp: `Grid` may be deleted during the execution of the program.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: I read the size of `Grid.points` from data file.

Comment: Well, yes, but are there still `Element`s around which contain pointers to the points of the `Grid` object when the latter is destroyed? Do those `Element`s still need access to the points?

Comment: Apologies, made a mistake. Please see the edit.

Comment: Please also [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one?rq=1) for more informations.

Comment: Ah, that shows the design better. Can we assume that `Element` and `Face` objects are *only* created as elements of `elms` and `faces` (i.e., inside `Grid`), or as temporaries (i.e. do not outlive a `Grid` object whose `points` they point to)?

Comment: Is that really a duplicate? Seems it's the wrong answer...

Comment: @Deduplicator what do you mean?

Comment: @dyp: Yes, exactly what you said.

Comment: @Jefffrey Aren't indices at least as good, if not better? Can even be serialized fast, if that's a consideration. Can also be memory-mapped without change, directly from the data-file.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't understand what you mean by indeces but he should probably consider an `std::smart_pointer` is the resource is shared between the 3 classes. Otherwise an `std::reference_wrapper` is a good idea as well (depending on the preconditions of the lifetime of `Grid`'s points. In any way to the question "Should I use smart or raw pointers. If I use smart pointers should I use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr?" the answer is in both links I've posted.

Comment: @Deduplicator The [second one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one?rq=1) is more recent, but with a little bit of research you can easily understand the first one.

Comment: His `Face`s and `Element`s only ever refer to `Vector3`s in the owning `Grid` vector. Thus, indices into the `Grid`s vector of all `Vector3`s are a natural type to use.

Comment: @Deduplicator except when you modify the vector. Then the indexes may be invalidated, while an `std::shared_ptr` is not.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Indices are never invalidated, unless the element is removed from the container. Iterators are, and pointers.

Comment: @Deduplicator Modifying the vector includes the case in which elements are deleted, then it's trivial to understand that positions are shifted and indices are invalidated in the sense that they do not refer to the same element anymore. In an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>`, the pointers to the resources (contained in the shared pointer) are never invalidated, only the iterators to the element (and only if that operation causes a reallocation).

Comment: @Jefffrey: Sorry, but that does not match with the OPs problem description.

Comment: @Deduplicator what doesn't match with the problem description?

Comment: @Jefffrey Arbitrary removals of points from the grid. Actually, any change of those points. OP has not added that to the question itself though, only mentioned it in the comments yet, after prompting.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh, I think I understand what you mean. I've reopened it and posted and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049401/use-smart-or-raw-pointer?noredirect=1#comment37079772_24049401) you specified that the precondition is that `Element` and `Face` objects are created in a `Grid` object with the elements of the container referring to the same `Grid` containers, therefore the lifetime of all three containers (`points`, `elms` and `faces`) is the same.

Now you have to consider two cases.

#### Semi-immutable `points`

In this case, `points` is guaranteed to never invalidate references to its elements (eg. it's never modified). Here you don't need any smart pointers, you can just use a simple `std::reference_wrapper` as follows:

```
struct Vector3
{
    std::vector<double> dim;
    Vector3 () : dim(3) {}
};

template<class Type>
using ref_vec = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Type>>;

struct Element { ref_vec<Vector3> points; };
struct Face    { ref_vec<Vector3> points; };

struct Grid
{
    std::vector<Vector3>  points;
    std::vector<Element>  elms;
    std::vector<Face>     faces;
};
```

Another solution, non equivalent to your example (`elms` and `faces` don't have direct access to the `Vector3` object) might be to use indexes:

```
struct Vector3
{
    std::vector<double> dim;
    Vector3 () : dim(3) {}
};

struct Grid
{
    struct Element { std::size_t point_indices; };
    struct Face    { std::size_t point_indices; };

    std::vector<Vector3>  points;
    std::vector<Element>  elms;
    std::vector<Face>     faces;
};
```

That is, you store the indices of `points`.

#### Mutable `points`

If the operations performed on `points` can invalidate references, then you might want to consider another container that does not invalidate references/pointers/iterators to the element.

For example [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) guarantees the validity of references for deletion/insertion at the beginning and end of the container.

Once you have chosen the correct container you can just apply the same ideas as above.

Comment: Will the first case compile since `reference_wrapper` has no default constructor?

Comment: @Shibli, [It definitely will](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28386ea7edba69ef). No `std::reference_wrapper` object is created.