# Implementing anonymous adapter instances in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

*Note: I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049590/smart-pointers-with-optional-ownership) which was swiftly closed as a duplicate. This new question concerns the actual design, so it should not be a duplicate of that question.*

I've got a class `B` which takes a single argument of type `C *` (an abstract base class). I control the definition of `B`.

I have a loose collection of objects (read: a bunch of member variables in other classes) with various interfaces (some of which I don't control). Some implement `C`, some do not. I wrote some adapters which extend `C` and provide the necessary functionality.

Now I'd like to construct an actual collection of `B` objects. Something like this:

```
vector<B> bvec;

bvec.emplace_back(&obj1.x); // obj.x implements C
bvec.emplace_back(new YCAdapter(&obj2.y)); // obj.y doesn't implement C
bvec.emplace_back(new ZCAdapter(&obj3.z)); // obj.z doesn't implement C
... // 5-10 more of these
```

With these disparate objects collected under a single vector, I can now do useful operations in a consistent way.

But, this code has an obvious memory leak, in that the Adapters are leaked. These are pretty tiny little classes with barely any functionality, and I'd prefer not to have to keep a list of these adapters just so I can destroy them later.

How can I have `B` can hold pointers or references to `C` objects, while owning and destructing adapters (but not C base classes)? Should I disintermediate `C` from `CAdapter`s with another base class? Or should I use some form of smart pointer? Or some other solution that my limited C++ knowledge has failed to provide?

Comment: If the number of classes is not that big, why not use `boost::variant` instead of custom adapters? Or, you can erase the types outright and store a generic pointer and a tag of some sort.

Comment: @oakad: `C` is an abstract base class providing an interface I care about. `B` is a class which wants to use that interface. Not all classes conform to the interface, but `B` shouldn't have to care about those classes that don't conform (I think it would sully the implementation of B).

Comment: Perhaps hold `C*` by `shared_ptr`, sometimes constructed with default deleter and other times with do-nothing deleter?

Comment: What I don't understand about your design is that if `B` needs its arguments to implement `C`, then how is it going to do anything useful with objects that don't implement `C`? And if it isn't doing anything useful with those objects, why add them to the `vector`?

Comment: @Praetorian: I have objects which are from a different library. They implement some functionality which I can convert into `C` functionality easily (hence the wrappers).

Comment: Since you don't want to muddy `B`'s interface by adding constructors that take pointers to the various objects, you could go the other route and *always* pass an adapter to `B`. Create a pass-thru adapter for objects that already implement `C`. Now, all your adapters implement `C`, and all are dynamically allocated and owned by `B`. `B` can store its argument in `unique_ptr` and not worry about conditional `delete`s and such.

Comment: I thought of that, actually, and I implemented it already (but with `shared_ptr` since my stdlib isn't fully C++11 compliant). You should write that up as an answer since I did use that solution in the end. Are there any hazards of using `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [smart pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> v;
v.push_back(std::shared_ptr{new X{}});
...
```

The object will automatically be deleted when its use count reaches 0.

Comment: What about the objects which are already `C`s? Those are owned by classes external to `B`...

Comment: @nneonneo `shared_ptr` can take custom deallocator, which can be used for objects that not owned by `B` by give it an nop deallocator. although I think you should reconsider your design

Comment: @BryanChen: Reconsider to what? Yes, this design isn't optimal, but what would I change it to?