# Comparing addresses of reference_wrappers

Tags: c++, c++11, reference-wrapper

How can I compare two `std::reference_wrapper`s by the references they hold? I want to see if the references of two `std::reference_wrapper`s are equal or not.

Edit: Sorry from confusion. I meant how to get the addresses of referents and compare them.

Comment: `r1.get() == r2.get()`

Comment: Do you want to compare the addresses of the objects the `reference_wrapper`s refer to (as the title suggests), or compare the objects themselves for equality (as the body of the question suggests)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `get()` member function returns a reference to the element referred to. You can then take the addresses of the referents directly.

```
std::addressof(r1.get()) == std::addressof(r2.get())
```

Comment: What? No. References do not have addresses. Here you are getting the addresses of the _referees_, and I'm not even sure that this is what the OP intended to ask for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry poor wording on my part. And I am quite sure OP wanted to compare *addresses* because of the question title.

Answer (score 5):

The member function [`std::reference_wrapper::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) will return the reference it holds. You can then compare the two referenced objects with:

```
const auto& a = ref_a.get();
const auto& b = ref_b.get();
if (a == b) {
    // …
}
```

The above will, of course, call `operator==` on the two objects (if the type is a class type).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I felt like helping one of the few guys [that actually listens](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24049899/493122) and tries to improve his code.

Comment: He obviously _doesn't_ listen, otherwise he still wouldn't be posting RTFM helpdesk questions.